# Play one channel in both speakers

Tags: audio, gom-player

Sometimes I come across a broken part of the video in GOM player - or elsewhere, however GOM player is my current concern. The broken part in question only has one of both stereo chanels working - so that the sound only goes from one reproductor.

Can I merge both audio channels or use one of the channels for both speakers? I tried to play with GOM's Audio configuration, but I haven't come across such option.